# Keyword Tags under 'Statistics by Tag' in robot framework

Tags: logging, tags, report, robotframework

I am working with robot framework and want to optimize the report and log window.

I add tags to my keywords in my robot script and I expected that these keywords would be list bellow 'Statistics by Tag'. But It didnt.

Example:

Robot script:

```
***Keywords***
FirstKeyword
   [Tags]   acceptance 
   Log      Keyword1

SecondKeyword
   [Tags]   acceptance 
   Log      Keyword2
  

***Test Cases***
Test1
   FirstKeyword

Test2
   SecondKeyword
```

Report/Log:
[image]

How can I add my tagged keywords to 'Statistics by Tag' so that I can just list the keywords with the selected tag.

Thanks.
Pouyan

Comment: Tags are for tests not keywords, just put the tag in the "Test1" and "Test2" and it will work

Comment: Thanks for replying. I need to mark some of my keywords in my robot script because they perform an important test. Is there a possiblity to mark these keywords or make them noticeable?

Comment: If the keyword *is* that important then it should be a test on its on don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though keywords do [support tagging, their purpose is different than what you intend](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-tags) - they are in the logs, and can be used for manipulating the html files produced from an output.xml, but they don't appear in the statistics section of the reports.

Imagine if it was the other way around, and they were shown there, what info would they bring? Remember that a keyword is an operation, while a case is a combination of such to assert a behavior - and slicing cases by a tag is usually what users want to achieve.

"Here are the stats on cases that had *a specific operation* in them" - what if that op was login, or navigation to a page in the SUT, or a DB assert; that would be just noise IMHO. A tag for verifying the page works as expected, or the system stores the data in DB correctly is the value, and that's achieved with tags on those specific cases.

Plus, tags are very often used to run specific set of cases. If that was extended to keyword ones, the framework should do much heavier parsing on selecting what to run - not only on the suites & cases, but on the keywords they use, going as deep as needed for embedded ones.

Comment: Hey Todor, thank you for your detailed answer. I understand what you explain.
I would like to list my tagged keywords in a separate view like statistics by tag. Is there any possibility?

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box; if *I* had to do it, I'd probably parse the output.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your repy. For my report of the automation test I need a good overview for my report. 
I have some keywords in my robot script which perform important test steps and I want to have these keywords in a seperate view. Or if it is no possibility for that to highlight these keywords to see these keywords immediately. I looked in the guide but didnt find a way for my issue. Or do you have an idea so that I can highlight or display my important keywords noticeable.

Comment: "Or if it is no possibility for that to highlight these keywords to see these keywords immediately." I don't know of such capability in the framework. You could add a logging on the WARN level - such logs are put on top of the results in the log.html, just after the summary table; that'll make them stand out.

Comment: Good hint. Thanks!